# How to fix this iissue , running mysql container wheneve i am trying db related operation

Tags: mysql, docker

`[image: error]

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  splitpay-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nodejs
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
      - redis
    environment:
      DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      
    networks:
      - my-networks    
    
  
  mysql-db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.mysql
    ports:
      - "3301:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"  
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db  
    networks:
      - my-networks    
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

  redis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - my-networks  


volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  my-networks:
    driver: bridge
```

`

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means there's no program running on that port. Post your `dockercompose.yml` file a bit more clearly

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the error output as plain text?  If there is a database-connection issue, how have you configured your application to connect to the database?  Also consider removing parts of the Compose file that aren't necessary for a [mcve] – the Redis container, the non-default `networks:`, the `volumes:` that overwrite the application image's code – but do include the MySQL image's `Dockerfile` if the standard `mysql` image doesn't have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address of the error message indicates your problem. `Error: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`.

127.0.0.1 is localhost. In a container context, localhost is the container itself. So your app is trying to connect to a database in your app container. That doesn't work. The database is running in another container with an address that's different from `localhost`.

To get it to connect to the database container, you need to use the hostname `mysql-db` rather than `localhost`.

Somewhere in your application (maybe in a connection string or in the code), you have the database address set to `localhost` and you need to change it to `mysql-db`.